# Sorting ArrayList<Object> Causing ClassCastException

Tags: sorting, kotlin, arraylist, classcastexception

My `ViewModel` observer returns an  `ArrayList<ContactObject>` (`contactsList`) which I want to filter and sort before setting `RecyclerView` with the modified `ArrayList<ContactObject>`.

Filter works as expected (it returns `List<ContactObject>` which I can cast to `ArrayList<ContactObject>`):

```js
var filteredContactsList = contactsList.filter { contact -> !contact.sites.contains(siteId) } as ArrayList<ContactObject>
```

But I can't get any of the sort functions to work - I have tried:

```js
var sortedList = contactsList.sortBy {(it as ContactObject).contactName} as ArrayList<ContactObject>
```

```js
var sortedList = contactsList.sortedWith(compareBy { it.contactName }) as ArrayList<ContactObject>
```

But I get the following exception:

```js
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Arrays$ArrayList cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList
```

So I'm trying to understand why these functions are returning a different type of list than `.filter` or if I am just using them incorrectly?

EDIT: I can get round this issue by converting it to ArrayList as below:

```js
var sortedList = ArrayList<ContactObject>()
sortedList.addAll(contactsList.sortedWith(compareBy { it.contactName }))
```

However, I have to create the additional variable in my ViewModel, which I was hoping to avoid (i.e. I was going to pass `contactsList.sortedWith(compareBy { it.contactName })` directly to the `recyclerView`)

Answer (score 0):

If you print the class name of the return types you will get to know that the class of the object returned by sortedWith is of type java.util.Arrays$ArrayList while the object returned by the filter is java.util.ArrayList. So even though the class name appears the same but when you cast the output of the filter it is successful(it is of type ArrayList) but the other one fails(java.util.Arrays$ArrayList has the same name but is nested inside Arrays class).

These both classes extend AbstractList class which in turn implements the List Interface. I think because of this you see the type as List but the concrete implementation is different. One is java.util.Arrays$ArrayList while the other is java.util.ArrayList .

Comment: Thanks Sandeep, so you think creating another ArrayList variable and adding the results, as I have shown at the end of the question, is the right solution?

Comment: Depends, If you so inclined towards sending data directly somewhere you could do something like
`func( ArrayList<ContactObject>(list.sortedWith(compareBy{ it.name}))) `

you won't create a reference for the object but it might not look like the most elegant solution or good practice.

An object is eligible for garbage collection when there are no more references to that object.

Comment: Do you really need an actual `java.util.ArrayList`?  From the code in the question, it simply looks like you need a `MutableList` implementation — which both of the `ArrayList`s in the question are.  So it would be much safer (as well as better expressing your intent) just to cast it to that.